# Unable to save .bmp image to server from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, gdi

In an ASP.net (C#) web app I have created a signature pad using HTML 5 canvas and java script. We are capturing the signature with touch devices (android and iOS).

When the signature is completed it sends the data from the canvas to the server where I convert it to a .bmp image and save it to a directory called signature files on the root program directory on the server using Bitmap.Save(location, Format). This has been working fine for several clients for many months until now.

Unfortunately I am currently catching exceptions but not sending them anywhere (huge mistake that I am currently working on rectifying). If I have to I will recompile the code with some exception outputs so that I can get more information but since its a new client I would love to be able to fix this asap and since the code has been working for a long time without issue, I'm optimistic that its a server setting.

Is there a security setting in IIS7 or Windows Server 2008 that may be blocking the app from saving a file to the server. If not is there something that may need to be installed on the server to allow the following:

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(suffix);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

string thePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveLocation);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(thePath + @"\image.png", FileMode.Create);

BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

bw.Write(imageBytes);

bw.Close();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetFileName(saveLocation)))
        {

            string filename = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf('.'));
            filename = filename + Path.GetRandomFileName();
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf('.'));

            theSaveLocation = saveLocation + @"\" + filename + "." + format;
        }


        ms = new MemoryStream();

        Bitmap input = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(thePath + @"\image.png");

        Bitmap result = ProcessBitmap(input, Color.White);

    result = (Bitmap)resizeImage((System.Drawing.Image)result, size);

    result.Save(theSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

    input.Dispose();
        result.Dispose();
        ms.Close();
```

Here's the process Bitmap function that I used above

```
private Bitmap ProcessBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
{
    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
    g.Clear(color);
    g.DrawImage(bitmap, Point.Empty);
    return temp;
}
```

Here's the resizeImage function that I used above:

```
private static System.Drawing.Image resizeImage(System.Drawing.Image imgToResize, Size size)
{

    int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
    int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

    float nPercent = 0;
    float nPercentW = 0;
    float nPercentH = 0;

    nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
    nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

    if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        nPercent = nPercentH;
    else
        nPercent = nPercentW;

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);


    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);


    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
    g.Dispose();

    return (System.Drawing.Image)b;
}
```

Comment: Have you deployed to a new server for the new client? Check your worker process has write access to the directory you're writing to. Does the target directory exist?

Comment: I think that If you are not swallowing the exceptions you should be able to see some details in the windows application log.

Comment: - It is a new server, How do you give write access to a worker process?

Comment: - What do you mean by swallowing the exception? Yes the target directory exists.